# How to replace forward slash with comma from date

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a new query on datepicker. I want to replace forward slash with comma (or dot) from date which is pick from datepicker. I tried some code below but it's not work fine.

Fiddle [`Here`](http://jsfiddle.net/PQfDc/161/)

HTML

```
<input type='text' id='txtDate' readonly='true' />
<input type='button' id='btnConvert' value='Change' /><br/>
Current Date : <span id='spnCurrentDate'></span>
```

Js

```
$("#txtDate").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true
});

$("#btnConvert").click(function(){
$("#spnCurrentDate").html($('#txtDate').val().replace('/', '.'));
});
```

Comment: `$("#spnCurrentDate").html($('#txtDate').val().replace(/\//g, '.'));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/PQfDc/165/)

use regular expression. THis will work for you

```
$("#txtDate").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true
});

$("#btnConvert").click(function(){
$("#spnCurrentDate").html($('#txtDate').val().replace(/\//g, ""));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the slashes. Try this:

```
$("#spnCurrentDate").html($('#txtDate').val().replace(/\//g, "."));
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FnNRr/)**

Comment: Don't encourage users to ask questions that have clear duplicates, by answering them.

Comment: @Cerbrus: It is not duplicate question it is different from that question.

Comment: @Subhash: The problem in your question is that only the first occurrence of `'/'` got replaced. That's what the linked question is about, and what it answers.

Comment: @Cerbrus even i can't answer after you marked it as a duplicate so i post it as a comment.

Comment: @Justcode: Maybe you shouldn't answer it, because it's already answered in the question this is a duplicate of. That's the entire point of dupe votes. There have been way too many questions about replacing all occurrences in a string, already.

Comment: @Cerbrus that's fine i accept your notice :)